# Cryptography: Make a stronger hash for password

Tags: security, hash, passwords, cryptography, system

I'm developing a system based on web and a client application; where the client make all the database queries in the server with the help of PHP and Http requests. The web system is developed in PHP / Mysql and the client application installed on the PC is developed in C#.

Good! in one phase, the client has to identify users through a login, this looks like a simple task BUT the server IP can be changed with the application configuration section. Considering this, any evil person can make phishing by entering an evil server ip address and then stealing passwords, the thing is, I will not send the password from the client in text/plain.

Right now I'm using md5 for password hashing (without salt, just the pure hash) and I'm using this only for store the password on the database.

After reading a bit, I realized that people doesn't recommend using md5 anymore, and use sha256 or above instead, I'm thinking of migrate to a better hashing algorithm and create my own salt.

As far as I know a salt is just a random piece of text you add to the hash, but I don't think it's the best option, so I was thinking on something:

Since hashes are based on hex values in lowercase with a fixed length (32, 64, etc.. depending of the algorithm), I can play with each ASCII code of each char of the hash with a sum of a fixed value loaded in a list (array) ex:

I have: abcd

ASCII code for each letter:

a -> 97

b -> 98

c -> 99

d -> 100

And then I sum a fixed value of the list (with a length of 32 / 64 integers depending) like this

a -> 97 + 5 = 102 => f

b -> 98 + 2 = 100 => d

c -> 99 + 7 = 106 => j

d -> 100 + 3 = 103 => g

So the result would be: fdje which replaces the hashing of abcd.

I don't know how safe could it be, and how difficult is for the hacker to determinate the technique I use, the thing is that the result has the same length as the hash, and is harder to determinate a salt, so if FOR ANY REASON IN THE HISTORY, hacker uses a rainbow table and catches a probable result, it WILL BE THE WRONG. What do you think about it?

Thank you...

Comment: Please don't design new security primitives without at least first deluding yourself that you're an expert.

Comment: What makes me nervous is this: “[…] where the client make all the database queries in the server with the help of PHP and Http requests.” Could you elaborate on this? What do you mean by the client makes the database queries? Does it generate them and send them to the database for execution?

Comment: [Don't roll your own crypto](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/20774). Use scrypt, bcrypt, or pbkdf2.

Comment: @Gumbo In order to avoid decompilation, and let a hacker get my database credentials (db, username, password, etc) I use some kind of web service. In other words, the application works like some kind of web browser, or web application (like HTML / JavaScript) and make requests to the server (Ajax / PHP). Also, I want to go this way because one of my tasks is to upload documents to the server and I don't want to use a lot of services like FTP, SSH, etc when I already installed a webserver that allows me to do a lot of things with C#'s WebClient class.

Answer (score 1):

A simple substitution cypher is unlikely to slow down a determined hacker for very long.

Your biggest problem is that somebody with your client could build up a table of the hashes you are generating for specific values. Enter `a` in password field, capture hash. Enter `b` in password field, capture hash. With that kind of data it would be pretty easy to reverse engineer your method, even if it was salted.

I would think your best bet is to use some kind of public/private key pair so that the client only trusts your server and won't communicate with anything else.

I also think you misunderstand salting - you don't add characters to the hash, you add them to the value you are hashing. Think `hash(password + salt)` instead of just `hash(password)`.

Answer (score 1):

> the server IP can be changed with the application configuration section. Considering this, any evil person can make phishing by entering an evil server ip address and then stealing passwords

This doesn't make sense as a threat model. If an attacker can execute code on the client to reconfigure the user's application, they can already intercept all the keystrokes before they go anywhere near the server.

> the thing is, I will not send the password from the client in text/plain.

The normal method to protect a connection is to use SSL, which would make it fine to send the password from client to server. The necessary server certificate would also take care of authenticating the server to the client (although this still can't fix the problem of a compromised client endpoint). You can use your own CA infrastructure if you don't fancy paying a commercial CA.

If you are proposing passing a hash from the client to the server instead of a password you've got a Password-Equivalent-Hash, which if leaked is subject to many of the same risks as a password. Also it means that both the client and the server have to agree on the hashing algorithm, so you can't include a salt, which means you're still stored easily-crackable unsalted hashes in the server database.

Running a fixed substitution cipher on the digits in a hex-encoded hash would offer a very small amount of obscurity which would deter only the laziest attackers. I don't think it's worth the bother when there are well-understood standard security systems that offer much better guarantees: HTTPS for the connection and bcrypt ([password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in PHP) for the password storage.

(If you *really* need to connect to a server you don't trust, there are PAKE algorithms like [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol), but it's a bunch of work, leaves open the question of how the password gets set up and managed in the first place, and without the connection-layer encryption the whole of the rest of your protocol is unprotected.)

Answer (score 1):

You might be misunderstanding how salts and salting a password means in general. Salting passwords are used to "defend" against rainbow tables (which are big tables of pre-computed values). Now, generating the rainbow table once is the most costly operation a hacker has to do and the whole concept of rainbow tables is to speed up brute-forcing a hash.

The point of a hash is to remove the possibility that a hash-table/rainbow table can be generated for one password and then used for another. Given that you have a **fixed** salt generation algorithm, any attacker can determine the algorithm and use it against you.

Salts should be generated **randomly** and stored in plain-text somewhere with the password itself. Salts should also be unique to each password (which should be pretty much ensured if you use a proper random salt generator). By doing that you ensure that a rainbow table for one password will be not-usable against another password.

Now thats done and dusted, we move on to the bigger problem: **using a simple hash algorithm for password storage.**

---

Without going into too much detail, the reality is as follows:

GPUs and other ICs (such as ASIC/FGPA) have become **too** fast. Simple hashing algorithms like `Message Digest 5`, `Secure Hash Algorithm 1/2` can be computed at mind-blowing speeds and passwords can be cracked like popcorn in a microwave.

To counter this, dedicated password-storage/hashing algorithms like `PBKDF#2`, `bcrypt` and `scrypt` have been developed which are purposefully resource-intensive and sequential (as in can't be parallelized, to an extent) to keep the GPUs and ASICs at bay.

Your post mentioned you are using PHP so let me introduce you this ridiculously simple solution you may choose to implement. Starting from PHP 5.5 there exist two key new functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` which do all the hard and complex work for you.

Consider this code:

```
$pass = 'foobar';

//Generates a password hash
$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Just like that, PHP has hashed the password for you using a recommended (`bcrypt` at the time of writing) password-hash and security salted the password for you and formatted the output into a single string for storage.

To verify if a given password is correct:

```
$pass_to_verify = ...

//$hash variable retrieved from the previous password_hash() function.
if(password_verify($pass_to_verify, $hash)){
    //Password is correct
}else{
    //Password is not correct
}
```

Using those two functions, you can be be ensured (as long as the folks at PHP don't mess up) that your passwords are secured against brute-forcing. Re-iterating a statement many people have been saying: **do not implement your own crypto unless you are fully aware of the whole concept of ciphers and hashing algorithms** (in that case, you probably won't even be posting on SO).